# DKPro doesn't work with Jython due to missing requests package

Tags: python, debugging, python-requests, jython, dkpro-core

I've followed the documentation of the installation of DKPro Core for natural language processing but have found that no matter what way I install it under Debian Jessie I cannot get it to work. It works fine with Groovy but not with Jython as documented at:

```
https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-core/pages/jython-intro/
```

I've installed Oracle Java, jip and jython and then the jip jar that gets compiled (supposedly, I'm not sure) into jython.

The error I obtain at the end is:

```
$ jython pipeline.jy 
jip [Checking] pom file http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.opennlp-asl/1.6.2/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.opennlp-asl-1.6.2.pom
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pipeline.jy", line 9, in <module>
require('de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.opennlp-asl:1.6.2')
File "__pyclasspath__/jip/embed$py.class", line 38, in require
File "__pyclasspath__/jip/commands$py.class", line 109, in _resolve_artifacts
File "__pyclasspath__/jip/commands$py.class", line 83, in _find_pom
File "__pyclasspath__/jip/repository$py.class", line 218, in download_pom
File "__pyclasspath__/jip/repository$py.class", line 218, in download_pom
File "__pyclasspath__/jip/util$py.class", line 71, in download_string
ImportError: No module named requests
```

I'm guessing most people will give me the answer, "install python-requests" using apt-get or pip. This does not work. This is not a python issue. Its a jython issue or some sort of strange environment issue. I'd appreciate any insight in to how to get it to work.

Comment: It seems to me this is a JIP issue with JIP not finding some dependency of itself. We tested this using JIP 0.8.3. Maybe for later versions of JIP, additional dependencies need to be installed. Could you please see if it works for you with JIP 0.8.3?

Comment: I'm using jip-0.9.13 and it doesn't work. Do you think that a specific version is required?

Comment: I tried installing jip-0.8.3 now, but what does it really do? Is it supposed to build and install a jip binary as is the case when you perform "pip install jip"? I ask because it definitely doesn't install a jip when you run: cd jip-0.8.3 && jython setup.py install

Comment: JIP is used in the DKPro Core Jython examples to download dependencies from Maven repositories. The `requires` function used in the Jython example (https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-core/pages/jython-intro/) is from JIP.

Comment: I'm not a python expert, but at the time I wrote the examples "jython setup.py install" did install jip into my local jython installation such that it was then available to my jython scripts. Looking at the stack trace you posted above, I can see that JIP code is executed but seems to fail when JIP tries to invoke liburl / liburl2.